# PHP button link (header) not responding

Tags: php, html, response-headers

I have created a button **start_btn** that is supposed link me to an internal header, but it is not responding at all.

It shows up, but even though I implemented other actions that it's supposed to take it, doesn't work.

```
    <?php
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    $_SESSION['msg'] = "You must log in first";
    header('location: login.php');
}
//////
if (isset($_POST['start_btn'])) {
    session_destroy();
    unset($_SESSION['username']);
    header('location: register.php');
}
//////
if (isset($_GET['logout'])) {
    session_destroy();
    unset($_SESSION['username']);
    header("location: login.php");
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="header">
    <h2>Home Page</h2>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <!-- notification message -->
    <?php if (isset($_SESSION['success'])) : ?>
        <div class="error success" >
            <h3>
                <?php
                echo $_SESSION['success'];
                unset($_SESSION['success']);
                ?>
            </h3>
        </div>
    <?php endif ?>

    <!-- logged in user information -->
    <?php  if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) : ?>
        <p>Welcome <strong><?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?></strong></p>
        <div class = "btn">
            <button type="submit" class="btn" name="start_btn">Start!</button>
        </div>
        <p> <a href="index.php?logout='1'" style="color: red;">logout</a> </p>
    <?php endif ?>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have created working login and register buttons and tried to implement their code into my new button, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Is your form setup for post?

Comment: Do you have a `form` somewhere on your page that holds the `button`?  Also, is the code above all in one page?  Is it exactly as above?  Because as-is, that wouldn't even run.  It's really hard for us to help debug things we can't see.

Comment: Thats not how it exactly looks like, the button is inside </body>
</html> and <div class="content" and the if is in <?php ?> brackets

Comment: So there's no `<form>`?  Element then?  Im not going to stick around guessing.  I'll say again that I _highly_ suggest showing your _actual_ code.

Comment: I've posted my code

Comment: if is not a form you can not use $_POST, insert the button in the form

Comment: Thanks guys, I didn't know what was that **form** , now it works